# Including files in php not being found

Tags: php, include

I am working on a php project and I am having problems with including files.

I have a php script which is located at myapp/reports/index.php. When a form is submitted it performs an ajax post to another phpscript located at myapp/reports/phpHander/submit.php.

Submit.php then has to include a php script which is used to send an email. This is done to ensure that same code can be used over and over again without it needing to be typed for each time it is need. This php script is located at ../../administrator/classes/send.php.

Up to this point is working fine however the send.php script includes another file to get app config settings which is located in administrator/appConfig.php. The problem is this appConfig.php isn't being found even if I put in the full web address of http://localhost/myapp/administrator/appConfig.php.

What am I doing wrong. I am using the php include function to do this and its working for everything else but it seems to have a problem then including another script from a different location.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http://localhost/myapp/administrator/appConfig.php` is only URL path.

You need absolute filepath like `C:/wamp/www/myapp/administrator/appConfig.php` (Windows) or `/var/www/myapp/administrator/appConfig.php` (Linux)

---

Anyways best way is make a file "dirs.php" in your root application directory with constant:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
```

where `dirname(__FILE__)` will be absolute path to your app directory.

With this knowledge you can include files in this way:

myapp/reports/index.php:

```
require_once('../../dirs.php');
include(ROOT_DIR . '/administrator/appConfig.php');
```

myapp/reports/phpHander/submit.php.:

```
require_once('../../../dirs.php');
include(ROOT_DIR . '/administrator/appConfig.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you include another PHP script, all the paths are relative to the calling script. So, it sounds as though your script is at myapp/reports/phpHander/submit.php and includes ../../administrator/classes/send.php, which then includes another script in that same directory. In this case, you need to use the path "../../administrator/appConfig.php". Alternatively, you could use absolute paths relative to the filesystem's root.

Comment: Nice explanation here:
http://brian.chipsofttech.com/blogs/brian/post/Different-Path-Types.aspx#site